# How to use an older version of GCC (2.7.2 or 2.95)?

Tags: gcc

I need an older version of GCC on Ubuntu 20.04. I am not sure if its even possible to install such old versions. I have tried multiple commands but none of them are working, e.g.

sudo apt-get install gcc-2.7.2 g++-2.7.2
Can anyone please guide me regarding this? Is it possible to get these versions? And if yes, how can I do it? Is there an older Ubuntu version that might have this version of GCC?

Comment: Maybe you should elaborate *why* you want to run a 20 year old piece of software? Is this the only solution to a given problem?

Comment: I need to install the earliest bash version (1.14.1) and it can not be compiled with the latest gcc versions.

Comment: The same question applies... ^^

Comment: My old post in this link may help you https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/204882/how-can-i-build-older-version-of-gcc

Comment: I still think the short answer is that installing 20-25 year old software will require a lot of manual tinkering. Nothing is impossible, but you must decide how much time you're willing to spend to get things to work.

Comment: A client demands it to be installed. :D

Comment: @ArturMeinild But is there a possibility that those softwares won't run on our current machines? Since the hardware used to be quite different at that time (late ninetees).

Comment: I seriously haven't got a clue.. 

Comment: Look up 'Docker'. It _may_ be easier to get it running as Docer as you can specify whatever envoirnment you want (probobly some very old version of Debian - it appears Docker Ubuntu only goes to 14.04, so I'd suggest trying [debian/eol](https://hub.docker.com/r/debian/eol). It has released all the way back to 2000, so you could try installing it in Docker. Remember to setup a volume for persistence.

Answer (score 2):

It's highly unlikely that such an old version can be installed normally.

But the [source code is available](https://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/misc/gcc/releases/gcc-2.95.3/), so it might be possible to get it to run by compiling it yourself and/or running it in a VM.

In any case, it may require some amount of tinkering to get something like this to work.